# Show div if another div has a certain string of text

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is probably easy for most of you, but being a beginner I am having a tough time.

I want to show div1 if div2 has the word foobar in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// get div 2
var div = document.getElementById("div2");
// get string content
var text = div.innerHTML;
// test if foobar is in text
if (text.indexOf("foobar") >= 0) {
    // if so set display to block.
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
}
```

Oh and if you like jQuery then :

```
if ($("#div2").text().indexOf("foobar") >= 0) {
    $("#div1").show();
}
```

Although using jQuery just for this is overkill. It's a nice syntactic sugar if it's on the page anyway.

Comment: Heh, +1 for jQuery _and_ noting that it's overkill. I still suggest a regexp over `indexOf`, though, so that looking for "and" doesn't find it in "sand".

Comment: @Phrogz the definition of "word" is ambiguous. But yes a regex is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (/\bfoobar\b/.test(document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

This uses a regular expression `/\bfoobar\b/` to test for exactly the string "foobar" with word boundaries at either end. "foobars" will not match, but "I said 'foobar'" will.

The `RegExp.prototype.test()` method takes a string and returns true if the regular expression can match somewhere in it, false otherwise.

We pass in `innerHTML` of the div, which is like the source code inside it.

I'm assuming that you have already hidden `div` by setting its `display` style to `none`, either via JS or via a stylesheet, e.g.

```css
#div1 { display:none }
```

Comment: @Phrogz innerText breaks in firefox. (And is IE-only extension, not part of the W3C specification)

Comment: @Raynos I thought `innerHTML` was also an IE-only extension, not part of the W3C specification.

Comment: @Raynos Seriously? Still. Wow, thanks for letting me know. @JaredFarrish Because it's an easy way to use word boundaries, and not make the mistake of finding a word that's actually part of a different, longer word.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc seems like it. It is in the HTML5 spec though. It's the easiest way to get text from nested content though. @Phrogz no need to call `.test` you can use the regex as a function directly to call `.test` indirectly.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) is "DOM Level 0", which means it was never formally specified. It was introduced first by IE, but was quickly adopted by the other browsers and so support is grandfathered in.

Comment: @Phrogz the old `.textContent || .innerText` is valid though. A bit more complex. I think `.nodeValue` does the same and works in ie/ff/chrome. (not sure about safari/opera or edge cases).

Comment: My allergy is regex, even if it's appropriate.

Comment: @Raynos Would that it were so, but no, neither of those are reasonable replacements for getting `innerText` in FF.

Comment: @Phrogz `.textContent` does exactly what you want in FF and is in DOM 3. It's just not in IE<9. `.nodeValue` should also get the text content but i'm not too sure about those edgecases.